# How to registered engine from tilt in Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tilt

I have a Ruby on Rails application. I don't understand how to register an engine from gem [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt). 
Of course, I installed and required tilt.
But, when I send http-request, the application doesn't know about tilt and its engines. I have the error:

```
Missing template welcome/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}
```

I understand that my application has only 7 handlers for "[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]", and it doesn't have handles from tilt.

How to include an engine from tilt to list of view handles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) is a "Generic interface to multiple Ruby template engines", not an engine itself. The use case you described looks like standard rails, you need to add the file "welcome/index.html" yourself.

If I misunderstood your problem, can you provide more information?

Comment: I've created the file "welcome/index.<my_format>". But it didn't work. Yes, you are right! It is just an interface. I had to implement an engine and registrate it. I've found an article how to do it. It is very useful. Here is the link: https://edruder.com/blog/2017/12/19/add-markdown-to-rails-5.html

Comment: But it didn't work => What's the error now? Can you also share your `routes.rb` and the controller?

Comment: now it's working. I read the article and understood how to deal with it.